# Select different user while connect to SQL Server with Windows Authentification

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssms

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server by using **Windows Authentication** with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I have several users created on the machine that runs SQL Server.

Login dialog box won't allow to select other users, except the one that is logged in for the current Windows session.

How can I log into Management Studio as a **different** user?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the SSMS icon, hold `Shift`, then right-click `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` with the year of the version you have installed and select `Run as Different User`.  You will be prompted for Windows login credentials that will be used in Windows authentication in SSMS.  You can use another Windows account here and then use SSMS as you typically would without making any additional changes.

Answer (score 3):

Proven by many years way of impersonation: a shortcut or bat to run SSMS:

```
runas.exe /noprofile /netonly /user:YourDomain\YourAccount ssms
```

The drawback: the password of AD user to be entered every time you hit that shortcut

If you have few versions of management studio, just replace ssms with a full path to required executable

When SSMS is started then connect to a remote server using windows authentication.

---

Another way is to impersonate that user after you made a login using your credentials:

```
USE master
EXECUTE AS LOGIN='Domain\AnotherUser'

SELECT SYSTEM_USER
```

However, this will require your account to have IMPERSONATE or SysAdmin permissions. Impersonation can be granted by:

```
GRANT IMPERSONATE ANY LOGIN TO [Domain\YourAdAccount]
```

Comment: Hi Alex, this is not working, it is not opening Management Studio, I am using the following command  runas.exe /noprofile /netonly /user:XXXXtrs\devadminam ssms, its not opening anything I have only one Management studio